# IDEA GUI Designer forms instrumentation failed with Java 11

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, java-11, gui-designer

I'm trying to migrate my swing project from Java 8 to Java 11. I encountered a problem with IDEA GUI Designer plugin. When I try to build the project, I get following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.codehaus.mojo:ideauidesigner-maven-plugin:162.2038.2:javac2
> (default) on project stockbox-provider-ib: command execution failed:
> Forms instrumentation failed for
> /Users/maciej/stockbox/providers/ib/src/com/goodsoft/stockbox/ib/view/IBConnectForm.form:
> /Users/maciej/stockbox/providers/ib/src/com/goodsoft/stockbox/ib/view/IBConnectForm.form:
> Class not found: javax.swing.JPanel -> [Help 1]

Until now, I was dealing with it by providing ***bootclasspath*** VM argument with paths to ***rt.jar*** and ***jce.jar*** in JRE, which includes Swing classes like below:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>

            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}</executable>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <bootclasspath>${env.JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/rt.jar:${env.JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/jce.jar</bootclasspath>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
```

Since Java 9 JDK no longer includes JRE, so I can't point them. Moreover, Java 9+ doesn't support ***bootclasspath*** VM argument. I have tried adding rt.jar and jce.jar from JDK 8 as global libraries in IntelliJ, but it didn't solved the issue. I have also tried to point this jars in JDK 8, but it didn't worked either.

Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: JDK 11 is _modular_. You need to research ___module path___ The module containing _Swing_ is `java.desktop`

Comment: @Abra I've changed plugin configuration like below to add module java.desktop, but with no success. The issue is present only while building to be precise.

     `<compilerArgs><arg>--add-modules=java.desktop</arg></compilerArgs>`